# Restrict column name changes/creation to not allow specific characters

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

Currently certain characters used in column names will break external programs, so I'm looking for a way to restrict specific characters ("." "_" etc) from being used, either with the creation of new columns, or editing existing ones.

For example, if a user tried to create the column "Random_Info", it would automatically rename it to "RandomInfo", and the same goes for editing an existing column: remove the offending characters before the change is made.

The issue with this is that it might create duplicate columns, I'm not sure what the best course of action is to handle that though.

It seems like Triggers might be what I need, but I've only got them working for editing the actual content of the columns, not a change to the column name itself.

A bit stuck on this one and google has failed me, hopefully I've provided enough information for someone to give an answer here!

Comment: You are looking for a DDL trigger.  Start with the documentation:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941(v=sql.105).aspx.